# Hosted a React.js website on Firebase that shows "Site Not Found" on saif-newaz.web.app but works fine on saif-newaz.firebaseapp.com

Tags: reactjs, firebase

[image]

This shows as the error but none of seems to be the issue and it's weird that it works on one of the web addresses but not on the other.

I have tried to deploy it multiple time. Even tried to create a new project and deploy it. It works there but can't seems to make it work on saif-newaz.web.app

Comment: For me it works only on https://saif-newaz.web.app/ and not https://saif-newaz.firebase.com/

Comment: Spelling mistake it's https://saif-newaz.firebaseapp.com/ and it works on saif-newaz.web.app ??

Comment: Both of those links are working so I don't see what the problem is.

Comment: Can you give me a screenshot? It doesn't work from my side

Comment: I have added a screenshot from end

Comment: I'm getting the same result from saif-newaz.firebaseapp.com and https://saif-newaz.web.app/. Maybe the problem has to do something with your phone? Try going to those websites on a different device.

Comment: I was also getting the same result from my laptop. That's why tried my phone.

Comment: Clear your browsing history everything,, press **Ctlr+f5**